# Runtime problems in TestNG asserts

Tags: java, arrays, testng, assert

I have a TestNG assertion which may occasionally fail due to the state of the object asserted (ArrayList element), and when it does, I would like to display this state.

I created an example which will fail in runtime, to illustrate the concept

```
import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;



@Test
public void sandbox() {
    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    assertEquals(arr.size(), 0, "The problem is: " + arr.get(0).toString());
}
```

I expected the assertion to pass and it will, when I remove the third argument (message). I see it's not a TestNG issue as execution is not stepping in the statement, but rather fails directly at this step with

```
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
```

What's the best approach here? I am thinking of a method which will take care of the exception, but perhaps there are better known ways.

Thanks

Comment: You created empty array and then trying to access element at index 0.
Clearly its going to throw error.

Comment: Yes, but I don't expect this statement to be evaluated at all because the assertion is supposed to be passed anyway in this case. (the argument is the message on failed asserts only). In real life situation this array is normally empty, but sometimes is not and when it's not, I would like to log the content.

Comment: In assertEquals: The first argument is the actual value, the second value is the expected value, and the third value is an error message to display in case of failure. If you display in your error message arr.get(0) - you have assumed that there is at least one element in the array. Therefore you will encounter IndexOutOfBoundsException, if the array contains 0 elements. Can you please specify what exactlly you are trying to achive?

Comment: @ShaharRotshtein as I said above, the array does not always contain zero elements. I just fail to understand why does the message logic (arr.get(0)) is even executed in runtime when it's supposed to be ignored by passing assertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below should work:

```java
import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;


@Test
public void sandbox() {
    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    assertEquals(arr.size(), 0, "The problem is: " + arr);
}
```

This is more practical as well, because if list is not empty it will print all values from the list instead of the first.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no other *pretty* way of doing it since all your arguments are passed at once to the callee, i.e. your method, so that the `arr.get(0)` must have been evaluated.

You may simply call for the `next()` element only if there is one using the `Iterator` over your collection:

```java
@Test
public void sandbox() {
    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator<Integer> it = arr.iterator();
    assertEquals(arr.size(), 0, "The problem is: " + (it.hasNext() ? iterator.next() : ""));
}
```